# How do I fix the misalignment of array data with the column header?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to display a 2D array, called 'grades', in tabular form. It has 5 rows and 20 columns, rows representing marks of students and column different tests.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int grades[5][20] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
                      };

printf( "       " );   // Offsets the column header from sidesways
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    printf( " [%d]", i ); // prints 20 column headers at top
    } 

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf( "\nrow[%d]  ", i );  // prints rows
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++){
        printf( "%-4d", grades[i][j] );
    } // inner for loop ends here
  } // outer for loop ends here
} // main ends here
```

The output is:

```
        [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
row[0]  1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
row[1]  1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   
row[2]  1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
row[3]  1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
row[4]  1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

As can be seen the data starts to misalign with from column `[11]` because of an extra digit in `[10]`. This way the data columns shift to left from their column header.

How do I fix it? And suppose if the data contained multidigit numbers then how can we print an "aligned" table (see eg. https://pastebin.com/nmbdgmHZ)?

Thank you!

Note: This problem is from chapter 6, exercise 6.9, of [C How to Program, 8/e](https://deitel.com/c-how-to-program-8-e/).

Comment: You get your math right. `[nn]` = 4 characters plus space, so 5 per column. You're only giving room for 4 with *no* space. Consider `[%02d]` as your first formatter for consistency.

Comment: *How do I fix it* You know how to set field width for printing, so why are you using spaces for alignment?  *how can we print a "good" table?* How do you want a good table to look?

Comment: By "good" table I mean an aligned table. Example: https://pastebin.com/nmbdgmHZ

Comment: Hint: use two different format specifiers: `printf( j <= 9 ? "%4d" : "%5d", grades[i][j] );` That's just one way of doing this. (You probably don't want _left justification_ of the grades...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 That solves the problem elegantly. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman thank you, I didn't know about use 0 in format specifier. Indeed, I learned a lot about format specifiers from the link provided by Oka (in answer).

Comment: Another: `printf( &" %4d"[j < 10], grades[i][j] );` A bit arcane, but worth working out for the learning experience :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%*d` allows you to pass an `int` to specify the [*minimum field width*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), letting you change the padding dynamically.

This works for your specific example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int grades[5][20] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
    };

    printf( "       " );

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf(" [%d]", i );
    }

    putchar('\n');

    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("row[%d] ", i);

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            printf("%*d ", 3 + (j > 9), grades[i][j]);
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

```
        [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
row[0]   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6 
row[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6 
row[2]   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6 
row[3]   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6 
row[4]   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

The calculation (`3 + (j > 9)`) would need to be changed for a different data set, but the principle remains.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int grades[5][20] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
                      };

printf( "         " );   // Offsets the column header from sidesways
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    printf( " [%2d]", i ); // prints 20 column headers at top
    } 

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf( "\nrow[%d]  ", i );  // prints rows
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++){
        //printf( "%-4d", grades[i][j] );
        printf( "%5d", grades[i][j] );
    } // inner for loop ends here
  } // outer for loop ends here
printf("\n");
} // main ends here
```

The output is:

```
          [ 0] [ 1] [ 2] [ 3] [ 4] [ 5] [ 6] [ 7] [ 8] [ 9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
row[0]      1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
row[1]      1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
row[2]      1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
row[3]      1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
row[4]      1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Also got a solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int grades[5][20] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                         {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                         {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                         {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                         {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};

    printf("    "); // Offsets the column header from sidesways
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%*s[%d]", (i < 10) ? 3 : 2, "", i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nrow[%d]  ", i); // prints rows
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            printf("%-6d", grades[i][j]);
        } 
    }     
}
```